# In VB.net, How can I access to a function in a class from an other function in a nested class?

Tags: vb.net, interface, nested-class

I'm developing in VB.net but I'm come from java and I have the idea to create a anonymous class who implements an interface like this:

```
int h = 4;

Object x = new iInterface({
    @Override void f(){
        h = 5;
    }
});
```

I didn't know how to do it, so I think to create a nested class who implments the "iInterface" but...

```
Class N
    Dim h = 4
    Class n
        Implements iInterface
        Sub f()
            h = 5
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

... VisualStudio puts a fluffy blue mat under h and says to me: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

What should I do? >___<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Class N
Shared h = 4
Class n
    Implements iInterface
    Sub f()
        h = 5
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for shared elements. Here is the documentation for that:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx
Otherwise you have to explicitly create an instance of that class in order to 
use it.