# creating a shared variable with inheritance

Tags: vb.net

My question is in relation to the below question:

[In VB.net, How can I access to a function in a class from an other function in a nested class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769457/in-vb-net-how-can-i-access-to-a-function-in-a-class-from-an-other-function-in-a)

By setting the variable h shared, are you making that variable available to all instances of the class as a single or static variable thereby creating the possibility for problems in the asker's future endeavors?  Or is my understanding of VB.net skewed?

If I'm right would that mean that the code would the need to be arranged like this:

```
Class N
    Dim h
    Class n
        Implements iInterface
        Sub f()
            h = 5
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

And instead create an instance of the object to use in consuming code?

Comment: Good question but nested classes are not inheritance.  Public nested are something most avoid.  If you really do mean inheritance, please clarify.

Comment: No, but the nested class implementing an interface is inheritance.i guess there's some info missing from the question to fully grasp the asker's goal.

Comment: an Interface is more like a contract indicating that a Type does implement certain properties and/or methods.  They are often used *instead of* inheritance because the various Types too different to inherit from a meaningful base class.

Comment: Fair enough. The asker did not show his interface and he's not extending anything. But the original question actually relates to anonymous inner classes in vb which, from my understanding of vb, isn't possible like it is in Java. You have to create a concrete class and reference it using an interface or inheritance. Or is my understanding flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared variable isn't part of the instantiated object. If you write

```
Dim o As New N
o.h = 1
```

Assuming h is shared, you will get a warning. You have to call it like this.

```
N.h = 1
```

When you have code in the class itself, you don't need to specify the class name. His code is actually

```
Class N
    Shared h = 4

    Class n
        Implements iInterface
        Sub f()
            N.h = 5
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Maybe this will help you understand it a bit more. This clearly show that each instance of n will be sharing the same h variable. Let's add a new function

```
Class N
    Shared h = 4

    Class n
        Implements iInterface
        Sub f()
            h = 5
        End Sub
        Sub ff()
            h = 12
        End Sub
        Function GetH() As Integer
            Return h
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class

Dim o1 As New n
Dim o2 As New n

o1.f()
o2.ff()

Console.WriteLine(o1.GetH()) ' This will print 12
Console.WriteLine(o2.GetH()) ' This will print 12
```

I think his question didn't have enough information to indicate if the shared variable will cause problem or not.

Comment: So then, yes, that is making h a static variable available to all instances of the class. Which would then mean that in order to avoid shared the asker would need to make h overrideable or must inherit

Comment: @RichardBarker in his sample n is it's own class, it does not inherit from anything not even N. Inheriting would be a totally different story.

Comment: Anonymous inner classes is what he was trying to do much in the same way java does. Is that even possible in VB?